# Html5 video source from input tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, tags

I want to make a webpage with an text-input element where I can put a url and at a button press to start playing video from that url. In other words, I want to make the url from the input to be the source of the video tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function write(){
                document.write(document.getElementById('url').value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Enter the source of the video.</p>

        <form id="frm1">
            URL: <input id="url" type="text" name="fname"><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="write()" value="Please Write the URL">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Enter the source of the video.</p>
        <form id="frm1">
            URL: <input id="url" type="text" name="fname"><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="write()" value="Please Write the URL">
        </form>
        <video id="myVideo" controls>
            <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg; codecs=dirac, speex">
            Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
        </video>
     <script>
         function write()
         {
             var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
             vid.src = document.getElementById('url').value;
             vid.play();
         }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but when I insert the url and click the button it gives me blank page.

Comment: I'll try to provide a fiddle in a while.

Comment: it was downvoted because  `value` will give you the file name not originally the file. files in a browsers have a `fakepath`. if you want them you will have to createDataUrl from the retrieved files.

Comment: The answer was from 2013. Are you sure createDataUrl has been in use from 5 years? Also, just a downvote doesn't inform anyone anything.